# radio box checking by javascript NOT working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been searching a lot and found out that one of the followings should work:

```
document.getElementById("inlineRadio1_gender").click();
$("#inlineRadio1_gender").prop("checked", true);
document.getElementById("inlineRadio1_gender").checked = true;
```

But none of them worked for me.

These are the radio boxes I use.

```
<input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_gender" id="inlineRadio1_gender" value="option1" checked="checked"> Male
<input type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions_gender" id="inlineRadio2_gender" value="option2"> Female
```

And I trigger a modal view by using this script

```
<script>
function td_Onclick(tr_object) {
    var input_staff_name = document.getElementById("staff_name");
    var input_staff_birthday = document.getElementById("staff_birthday");
    //var input_staff_men = document.getElementById("inlineRadio1_gender");
    //var input_staff_women = document.getElementById("inlineRadio2_gender");
    var input_staff_phone = document.getElementById("staff_phone");
    var input_staff_cellphone = document.getElementById("staff_cellphone");
    var input_staff_email = document.getElementById("staff_email");
    var input_staff_zip = document.getElementById("sample2_postcode");
    var input_staff_address = document.getElementById("sample2_address");
    var input_staff_address_ext = document.getElementById("sample2_address2");
    var input_staff_date_join = document.getElementById("staff_date_join");
    var input_staff_salary = document.getElementById("staff_salary");
    var input_staff_mainjob = document.getElementById("staff_mainjob");

    //document.getElementById("inlineRadio1_gender").click();
    //$("#inlineRadio1_gender").prop("checked", true);
    //document.getElementById("inlineRadio1_gender").checked = true;
    //document.getElementById("inlineRadio2_gender").checked = false;

    @foreach($staffList as $staff)
        if( tr_object.id == {{ $staff['id'] }} )
        {
            input_staff_name.value = '{{ $staff['name'] }}';
            input_staff_birthday.value = '{{ $staff['birthday'] }}';
            input_staff_cellphone.value = '{{ $staff['cell']}}';
            input_staff_phone.value = '{{ $staff['phone']}}';
            input_staff_email.value = '{{ $staff['email']}}';
            input_staff_zip.value = '{{ $staff['zip']}}';
            input_staff_address.value = '{{ $staff['address']}}';
            input_staff_address_ext.value = '{{ $staff['address_ext']}}';
            input_staff_date_join.value = '{{$staff['date_join2']}}';
            input_staff_salary.value =  '{{$staff['salary']}}';
            input_staff_mainjob.value = '{{$staff['task']}}';

            /*
            if('{{$staff['gender']}}' == 'female'){

                document.getElementById("inlineRadio1_gender").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("inlineRadio2_gender").checked = true;
            }
            else if('{{$staff['gender']}}' == 'male'){
                document.getElementById("inlineRadio2_gender").checked = false;
                document.getElementById("inlineRadio1_gender").checked = true;
            }
            */
        }
    @endforeach
    $('#add_staff').modal('show');
}
</script>
```

`@foreach`, and `{{ $staff }}` things are there because I use `Laravel` and `Blade` for this project.

And I commented out few lines because they don't work at all.

Interestingly, all other lines for other kinds of input form fields in this code works perfectly, but not those radio boxes.

Is there something i've been missing?

Comment: Are those element ids unique? It doesn't make sense to select elements by id within a loop.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, just tried super unique ids to double check their uniqueness and nothing changed. You can just ignore the loop, i've deleted them all and tried to change the single element but failed.

Comment: OK. Well `document.getElementById("inlineRadio1_gender").checked = true;` should work if the element exists at the moment when that code runs. What does `console.log(document.getElementById("inlineRadio1_gender").value)` show? (Also, you shouldn't need to set `.checked = false` for the other radio button in the same group, that should happen automatically when you set `.checked = true`.)

Comment: @nnnnnn - It turns out that it uses iCheck javascript library which only allows to use their own way to change states... Thanks a lot for helping out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaus06techian/dtrqgea7/)

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender1" value="option1"> Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender2" value="option2"> Female
<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<button onclick="showVal()">Show Value</button>
<button onclick="getVal()">Get Value</button>
```

JS

```
function showVal() {
  if (document.getElementById("gender2").checked) {
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Female";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Male";
  }
}

function getVal() {
  var val = document.getElementById("gender2").value;
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = val;
}
```

Works just about right

Comment: It turns out that it uses iCheck javascript library which only allows to use their own way to change states... Thanks a lot for helping out though.